# web scraping/export to CSV with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping

ruby n00b here in hope of some guidance. I am looking to scrape a website (600-odd names and links on one page) and output to CSV. The scraping itself works fine (the output correctly fills the terminal as the script runs), but I can't get the CSV to populate. The code:

```
   require 'rubygems'
   require 'nokogiri'   
   require 'open-uri'
   require 'csv'

   url = "http://www.example.com/page/"
   page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

   page.css('.item').each do |item|
     name = item.at_css('a').text
     link = item.at_css('a')[:href]
     foo = puts "#{name}"
     bar = "#{link}"

     CSV.open("file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
       csv << [foo, bar]
     end
   end

   puts "upload complete!"
```

...replacing the `csv << [foo, bar]` with `csv << [name, link]` just puts the final iteration into the CSV. I feel there's something basic I am missing here. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing `CSV.open` for every single item. So it's overwriting the file with the newer item. And hence at the end, you're left with the last item in the csv file.

Move the `CSV.open` call before `page.css('.item').each` and it should work.

```
CSV.open("file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  page.css('.item').each do |item|
    name = item.at_css('a').text
    link = item.at_css('a')[:href]
    csv << [name, link]
  end
end
```

Comment: You probably give the code him. It is actually, `page.css..` should be, inside the `CSV.open() { .. }` block.